# Selecting table and trying to query results with PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql, select, record

I have a database which contains 2 tables. In the second table there are numerous records and I'm trying to echo out the latest id (MAX id) to the page using PHP. There is something wrong with my code and I don't know what that is:

```
$sqlCount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM records"; 
$sql = "SELECT id,preview,description FROM records"; 
$pn = (isset($_GET['pn'])) ? $_GET['pn'] : 1; 
$res = upagination($con, $sql, $sqlCount, $pn, 6); 
$list .="<table border=0>"; 
foreach ($res['rows'] as $row) { 
    $list .="<tr>"; 
    $list .="<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['preview'] . "</td><td>" .          $row['description'] . "</td>"; 
    $list .="</tr>"; 
} 
$list .="</table>"; 
$paginationCtrls = ""; 
if (isset($res['backLink'])) { 
    $paginationCtrls .= "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pn=       {$res['backLink']}\">Previous</a>"; 
} 
if (isset($res['numbers'])) { 
    foreach ($res['numbers'] as $number) { 
        if ($number === $res['current']) { 
            $paginationCtrls .= "$number"; 
        } 
    (some deleted code to shorten this a little)
    }
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <style type="text/css"></style>  
    <title>Humorweb</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="videos">
    <meta name="description" content="Humorwebsite.org -collection of the    funniest videos and photos from the internet!-">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.humorwebsite.org/style_main.css">
</head>  
<body>  

    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">  </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="links">
                <a href="https://www.humorwebsite.org/">HOME</a>
                <a href="https://www.humorwebsite.org/videos.php">VIDEOS</a>
                <a href="https://www.humorwebsite.org/photos.php">PHOTOS</a>
                <a href="https://www.humorwebsite.org/about.php">ABOUT</a> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="context">
            <div id="context-text"></div>
            <div id="context-kuva">
                <br>
                <div id="nakki">
                    <?php echo $list; ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The last row I'm trying to echo out is the `$list` variable, but I get nothing. I have made a CSS on this file and define width, height, position, and float properties, but end up getting nothing from database.

Comment: did you var_dump your $res variable to see if you're getting those values?

Comment: I changed the script from
    <?php echo $list; ?>
into:
    <?php echo $list;
    var_dumb ($list); ?>

not working... still empty div

Comment: check your dev tool if it is at least writing <table border=0> or not. if it is writing this, then there's obviously error in your db fetch method. ( May be)

Comment: Oh now its showing up the $list, with echo script.. so var_dumb is not necessary i think.. Problem now is that its showing everything from the table and i only need the last record what i have added the last...

Comment: var_dump method is for dumping a variable to see its value and data type. both echo and var_dump is not necessary, var_dump is for debugging manually. anyway, what you want? the last record you added? or the last record added from somewhere else?

Comment: last record i added.. for example i upload new video to my site, and the last ID is 49, i want to show only the 49... im trying to echo it out but no results yet.. tried this: SELECT * 
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1

not working atm -.-

Comment: I think i got it working... cheers pal!

Comment: use last insert id according to your api, if you use mysql or mysqli or pdo, use the appropriate method for that. that will give you the last insert id number from that you you inserted from the current connection and fetch the row with that id. that's it.